# Get Image URL of photo with UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to select images. I was hoping to get the local path too.

I am doing this for images in an album using

`info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL`

In the case of an image using the camera this is `nil` however.

Is it possible to capture this path using `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but with another key:

```
info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
```

or

```
info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage
```

Please note that the object there will be UIImage type, not URL

Camera photos are not saved by default and don't have local path. So you need to save it by yourself. E.g.:

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
    try? image.pngData()?.write( .... )
}
```